# update gitlab source to omnibus: no rpm?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-8, gitlab-7

I'm attempting to migrate from a GitLab 7.1.0 (Source) installation (on Centos6) to latest omnibus (on Centos7) using these instructions:

https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/update/README.html#upgrading-from-non-omnibus-postgresql-to-an-omnibus-installation-using-a-backup

Essentially it boils down to:

1. Set up a new machine,
2. Install the omnibus version on the new machine that matches your source version,
3. Do an "backup" from the source version,
4. Restore that backup into the omnibus version,
5. update the omnibus version to latest.

I'm stuck on #2.  I've added the GitLab repo, but the oldest version of the "gitlab-ce" package available is 7.10.0.  Also they're named weirdly, e.g. "7.10.0~omnibus-1", "7.10.0~omnibus.1-1", etc. instead of simply "7.13.0-ce.0.el7".

What are my options?  If I install 7.13.0 Omnibus from the repo then try to restore a backup from 7.1.0 into it, should I expect that to work?  Will I lose data?

Is there a 7.1.0 omnibus RPM available somewhere?

If the new machine needs to be Centos6 in order to install a 7.1.0 omnibus package then I can reimage.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the [official RPM repo](https://packages.gitlab.com/app/gitlab/gitlab-ce/search?filter=all&q=&dist=el%2F7) it looks like 7.10 is the oldest version of the omnibus available for CentOS.

I think your best option is to perform the source upgrade outlined in [6.x-or-7.x-to-7.14.md](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/6.x-or-7.x-to-7.14.md) which should let you upgrade to v7.14. Then you can resume the normal "*upgrade source installation to omnibus installation*" method you found.

Also, in case it's helpful, the [docs repo](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master/doc/update) has incremental source upgrade procedures for many more versions.